# mysql help need to add number to every column

Tags: mysql

I need to add 0.25 to every number in a single column and im not sure how to do it. 
Here is the table I need to add 0.25 to everything in the p_rentfee column with a single statement.

```
p_code  p_descript      p_rentfee p_datlatefee  p_rentdays

1       Standard        2         1             5
2       New Release     3.5       3             3
3       Discount        1.5       1             5
4       Weekly Specia   l         1             7
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a normal `update` query.

```
UPDATE `table` SET `p_rentfee` = (`p_rentfee` + 0.25)
```